# How to handle object destruction in a custom container?

Tags: c++, memory, stack, destructor

I'm writing a custom Stack container that stores its elements in a fixed-size array:

```
template<typename T, uint32 TCapacity>
class Stack {
    // Member functions omitted
    T mData[TCapacity];
    uint32 mSize;
};
```

When an element is popped off the stack, I can just decrement the size. However, I think that if the item is popped off the stack, you'd also expect the destructor to be called on the object.

So, I could manually call the destructor on the object when popping, like so:

```
void Pop() { 
    assert(mSize > 0);
    mSize--;
    mData[mSize].~T();
}
```

However, when the Stack object itself is destructed, doesn't that cause the destructor to be called again for each object in mData, which could effectively "double destruct" certain elements? It might not be safe to double destruct all types, so this doesn't seem like a good idea.

I guess one alternative approach would be to construct a new object to overwrite the previous object, but that seems kind of inefficient potentially:

```
void Pop() { 
    assert(mSize > 0);
    mSize--;
    mData[mSize] = T();
}
```

The only other thing I can think of is to have the data array just be an array of bytes (unsigned char) and then deal with the extra complexity of constructing/destructing objects inside that raw memory. Which doesn't seem ideal, but maybe it's the true solution?

Does anyone have insight into a good way to deal with this? I imagine that a built-in container like std::vector also has to deal with this problem (though of course the data memory is allocated from the heap in that case).

Comment: What you're missing is [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new). It constructs an object into preexisting storage instead of allocating. Containers like `std::vector<T>` don't actually own a `T[]` array. They use an allocator to obtain storage on which they perform placement `new` to insert elements and explicitly call the destructor like you proposed to remove them later. You can use `std::allocator<T>` to easily get and free storage.

Comment: Ok, makes sense - so the key to avoiding a "double delete" here is to NOT have an array of type T. This stops the destructors for each element from being called when it goes out of scope. Something that appears to work (so far) is to define a fixed-size array of bytes `unsigned char mData[TCapacity * sizeof(T)];` I can then use reinterpret_cast when I need to treat it like an array of T: `reinterpret_cast<T*>(mData)[index] = instanceOfT`.

Comment: @kromenak basically, yes. However you should use [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) instead of a raw array.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the note - I overlooked the alignment issue, but I could absolutely see that being a problem. The memory buffer should be aligned for the particular type T.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the key is to not have an array of type `T`. You want an array of something like `optional<T>`, i.e. a type which can hold a `T` or hold nothing. But in this case, the container knows which items are populated, so the `optional<T>`'s internal knowledge of whether it holds a `T` is unnecessary.

For example, the following optional-like type should work:

```
template <typename T>
union storage
{
    char no_value_ = {};
    T value_;

    constexpr void assign(T&& obj)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>)
    {
        this->value_ = std::move(obj);
    }

    constexpr void assign(const T& obj)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T>)
    {
        this->value_ = obj;
    }

    constexpr void reset() noexcept
    {
        this->value_.T::~T();
        this->no_value_ = {};
    }
};
```

But this type itself is difficult to use, because it doesn't know whether it holds a value.

So, when you use it in a container, you must be particularly careful:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Capacity>
class stack
{
public:
    constexpr stack() noexcept = default;

    constexpr stack(const stack& other) noexcept
        requires std::is_copy_constructible_v<storage<T>>
        = default;

    constexpr stack(const stack& other)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T>)
        : size_{other.size_}
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size_; ++i)
            data_[i].assign(other.data_[i].value_);
    }

    constexpr stack(stack&& other) noexcept
        requires std::is_move_constructible_v<storage<T>>
        = default;

    constexpr stack(stack&& other)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>)
        : size_{std::exchange(other.size_, 0)}
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size_; ++i)
        {
            data_[i].assign(std::move(other.data_[i].value_));
            other.data_[i].reset();
        }
    }

    constexpr ~stack()
        requires std::is_destructible_v<storage<T>>
        = default;

    constexpr ~stack()
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size_; ++i)
            data_[i].reset();
    }

    constexpr void push(T&& obj)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>)
    {
        assert(size_ < Capacity);
        data_[size_++].assign(std::move(obj));
    }
    constexpr void push(const T& obj)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<T>)
    {
        assert(size_ < Capacity);
        data_[size_++].assign(obj);
    }

    constexpr T& top() noexcept
    {
        assert(size_ > 0);
        return data_[size_-1].value_;
    }

    constexpr const T& top() const noexcept
    {
        assert(size_ > 0);
        return data_[size_-1].value_;
    }

    constexpr void pop()
    {
        assert(size_ > 0);
        data_[size_--].reset();
    }

private:
    std::size_t size_ = 0;
    storage<T> data_[Capacity];
};
```

See a [full example](https://godbolt.org/z/3ar4r51Tb).

Comment: Typically one’d use std::aligned_storage (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage).

Comment: Although in common use, std::aligned_storage has significant downsides including being constexpr-hostile. Note that std::optional if implemented in standard C++ cannot use it. My type likewise was to represent storage for an optional value (with the has_value externalized), and I had no particular reason to disallow it in constexpr contexts. Another downside is that std::aligned_storage may also be deprecated in C++23 and eventually removed from C++ because the committee library working group (at least) thinks it shouldn't be used: https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/197

Comment: Ah, I think I understand this approach. So, the fact that the "T" is in the union stops constructors/destructors from being called automatically. Presumably creating an array of union objects results in correct alignment too, though I'm not too familiar with how unions deal with that personally. On my end, I did need to add a constructor/destructor to the union to have it work with a more complex class.

Comment: For std::aligned_storage, even if it is deprecated/removed at some point, it seems that you can replicate it's behavior with something like `alignas(alignof(T)) unsigned char data[Capacity * sizeof(T)];` in this sort of scenario. Though the other issue about constexpr-hostile may still be a problem!

Comment: Yes, the union prevents the constructors/destructors from being called automatically. The only special members a union has are those which are trivial on all members. A union is pointer-interconvertible with all members, so the alignment has to be as aligned as each member. Likewise, the size has to be at least as large as the largest member. The constructor shouldn't be necessary because there was a member-initializer, but that's GCC bug #98423. Yes, a destructor is necessary. Also, assignment operators for stack. Also, std::construct_at should be used to switch union members.

Comment: Also, yes, the recommended replacement in P1413 for code already using aligned_storage is an aligned char-buffer. IMO, the deprecation itself isn't as much of a problem as it is an indicator that it is currently not the best solution for what it allegedly solves, and there's not interest in improving it. Compare P0784, P1330, P2231 where there is active investment in improving union as it applies to these problems.